# How to set the Initial setup screen that will come only when application Executed first time in Android applicaton

Tags: android

I am developing an android application. 
I want to provide a screen that will ask the user name and password from the User when application runs first time after installation not from further execution.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess what you are looking for is some kind of [persistent data storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html).

You could display a dialog asking for the info only if you do not find it in your persistent store and make sure you store it once you obtain it.

Answer (score 2):

When you start the application, check the `SharedPreferences` for a key; if they key does not exist, create it and show the "First Screen".

Comment: A Database may be a better store for a password. In any case do not store the password as plaintext.

Comment: I suppose it shouldn't matter where it's stored as long as it is encrypted in some way.

Comment: For two fold security enhancement its a better approach to:
1)Store in a secured location(Database is secured compare with normal storage).
2)Encrypt it.
Neither of the two is 100% fool proof but 2 way security is better than one way!!

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Gabriel Negut, use **SharedPreferences**. This is an example

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("mypreferences", MODE_PRIVATE);
boolean isFirstUsage = prefs.getBoolean("first_usage", true);

if(isFirstUsage) {
    // show login screen
    <your_code_here>

    // save preferences
    Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("first_usage", false);
    editor.commit();
} else {
    do_something_else();
}
```